# Scroll UITableView up when keyboard appears in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

I have a `UITableView` with 7 cells and every cell has a text field inside it. When the keyboard appears it hides the last cell so it is quite difficult to see what has been input until and unless the keyboard disappears.

Can anyone guide me how I can scroll this `UITableview` up when the keyboard appears so I don't have this problem?

Comment: A tableview is just a UIScrollView subclass, the answer provide in the official documentation can be used https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1

Comment: This was in objective-c . I have a swift version now, if anyone needs it in future.                             NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown:"), name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

Comment: and then the function body like this:func keyboardWasShown(sender: NSNotification) {
        let info:NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
        let kbSize:CGSize = (info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue.size)!
        let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,kbSize.height,0.0)
        tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        
    }

Comment: func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
        
        let contentInsets:UIEdgeInsets  = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }

Comment: The best solution ever is you can find here : https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, textField.center.y-60), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: interesting idea, but does not work in all possible cases correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use thiese simple set of classes https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

**How to use:**

For use with `UITableViewController` classes, drop TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h into your project, and make your UITableView a TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView in the xib. If you're not using a xib with your controller, I know of no easy way to make its UITableView a custom class: The path of least resistance is to create a xib for it.